# What is a general purpose of "Update SQL layer" in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, sql, qgis-3

Can someone explain to me, what is a general purpose of "Update SQL layer"?

When I "update" it becomes not editable... (see gif ▼)

[image]

Comment: Under many conditions SQL databases allow the data to change, even if the same data is being read/edited by several users at the same time.  Those changes are not replicated live in QGIS, you need to "Update SQL layer" to see them.
If you could edit before but not afterwards... that's a bit more complex. That could be caused by QGIS but also by the database itself, the query being read, or the communication between QGIS and the database.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the layer becoming uneditable after selecting and applying an SQL query via "Update SQL Layer" on the layer context menu, I discovered selecting "Change Data Source" from the same context menu and then just reselecting the original data source returns the table to editable.

I haven't tested this but my guess is the problem results from "Update SQL Layer" replacing the original data source with a database view (which are not editable). So reselecting the original source does the trick. I think no matter what you do in that SQL window it always creates a view even with just `SELECT * FROM "thetablename"`. This is my theory, anyways. Either way reselecting the original table works to recover editability.

Using set filter is probably the best idea. I am guessing the project does the filtering of what is displayed